# How to get specific value by BeautifulSoup?

Tags: beautifulsoup

I try to get some specific text using BeautifulSoup but couldn't figure it out.

All I need is the numbers with the "THIS TEXT" block (`56789`), not "SOME TEXT"...

Can someone point what's wrong with my code?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def foo():
    response = """
    <div class="data_content_blog">
        <div class="data_content">
            <h5 class="large"> SOME TEXT </h5>
            <p class="large some-text">12345</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="data_content_blog">
        <div class="data_content">
            <h5 class="large"> SOME TEXT </h5>
            <p class="large some-text">34567</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="data_content_blog">
        <div class="data_content">
            <h5 class="large"> THIS TEXT </h5>
            <p class="large this-text">56789</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    """

    soup = BeautifulSoup(response, features="html.parser")
    soup_1 = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "data_content"})

    for s_1 in soup_1:
        s_2 = s_1.find("p").attrs["class"][0]
        s_3 = s_1.find("p").attrs["class"][1]

        if s_2 == "large" and s_3 == "this-text":
            print(s_2, s_3, "<- here")
            # get the number 56789 ???
        else:
            print(s_2, s_3)
```

Answer (score 1):

If class "this-text" is unique, you can select it and then `.find_previous()` tag:

```
num = soup.select_one(".this-text")  # or soup.find(class_="this-text")
h5 = num.find_previous()
print(h5.text, num.text)
```

Prints:

```
 THIS TEXT  56789
```

Comment: I got the number with the code example (hard-coded html) here but not from the actual web site. The numbers come from a json at the end of the web page, like; `var somevarsjson = [{"some-text-1": "12345", "some-text-2": "34567", "this-text": "56789"}]`.

Comment: @ssd So the values aren't inside the HTML? Then you need to use other methods than `beautifulsoup`. For example `re`/`json` modules etc.

Comment: When I use "inspect" (inside Chrome browser), I can see the values in-place but when I use `response = requests.get("url")` and save `response.text` in a file, the values appear to be at the very end of the text, stored as a "json" dictionary.

Comment: @ssd The values are inside `<script>` tag, so `beautifulsoup` doesn't see it - it doesn't evaluate javascript. You can extract these values with `re` for example.